# Empty test suite - running Karma/jasmine tests with WebStorm 8

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine, webstorm, karma-runner

I have a problem to run my tests in Webstorm 8, here is my conf file :

Here is my AngularJS controller :

```
angular.module('monApp').controller('DashboardCtrl', [
    '$scope', function ($scope) {
        'use strict';

        $scope.foo = 'bar';
    }
]);
```

And my test file :

```
describe('Controller: DashboardCtrl', function () {
    'use strict';

    var DashboardCtrl,
        scope;

    beforeEach(module('monApp'));

    beforeEach(inject(function ($controller, $rootScope) {
        scope = $rootScope.$new();
        DashboardCtrl = $controller('DashboardCtrl', {
            $scope : scope
        });
    }));

    it('dashboard should be defined', function () {
        expect(scope.foo).toBeDefined();
        expect(scope.foo).toBe('bar');
    });
});
```

These are very simple, I followed steps of many tutorials, first installed node, then install karma with **npm install**, and when i run karma with **karma start my.conf.js** the test pass but it shows Empty test suite.

I precise that in my project, I just have 5 files :

- angular.js
- angular-mocks.js
- the controller
- test file
- conf file

In the config file, i have added these 4 files with :

```
// list of files / patterns to load in the browser
files: [
    'angular.js',
    'angular-mocks.js',
    '*.js'
],
```

When I try to throw the test by right-click I get an error telling : **describe is not defined**.

Thanks.

Comment: It's most likely that angular-mocks.js is missing, check paths and if it's loading in your browser

Comment: I had problems with that first it displayd Warning, so I change the basePath in the config file, and all my files seem loaded now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried to restart from scratch and it appears that my instantiation of my app module wasn't fine, this is better :

```
var app = angular.module('monApp', []); 
app.controller('DashboardCtrl', ['$scope', function ($scope) { ....
```

And the first problem "empty test suite" was due to wrong basePath in the config file. Anyway, thanks for your answers !

Answer (score 0):

Your my.conf.js must contain :

```
frameworks: ['jasmine']
```

And Karma need the bridge to Jasmine framework to be installed :

```
npm install karma-jasmine --save-dev
```

By default, karma loads all installed plugins which are starting with "karma-".

Comment: It's exactly what I did to install it. And my conf file contains this line too. In the node_modules dir I have karma, karma-chrome-launcher and karma-jasmine, you think something is missing ?

Comment: do you use local or global karma installation to run tests?  Can you try running karma in terminal using the same command (node path/to/karma/karma start /path/to/config/karma.conf.js) - does it work?

Comment: Right. Have you installed karma & plugins globally (-g option) ? Maybe you run 2 differents instances of karma : The global one via console ( with karma-jasmine plugin) and the local one via Webstorm (in your project directory). Check that Websotrm uses the good instance (Run configurations).

Comment: I tried using the terminal with global installation and chrome is launching and in debug view i have a "no module error" in the chrome console it doesn't find my angular module, any ideas ? Is it linked with what you sayd ?

Comment: If I understand well, your test is launched and it fails for line `beforeEach(module('monApp'));` in your test file, meaning that your problem with karma plugins is over, right ?